# CRON Datastore Admin Backup

Tags: google-app-engine

I have Google App Engine with High Replication.
I have enabled Datastore Admin and taken backups and coppied data to oter apllications

Anyone know if it is possible and if yes how one would set up so the DataStore took a backup at set times like a CRON job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As announced last night with 1.6.5 this is now available.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't available yet, but we hope to ship it as part of SDK 1.6.5. See the prerelease SDK release notes here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine/pxjxp1tQNg8